# Autolayout - UIView animation from the bottom of the screen

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, autolayout

I am using autolayout in my application. I have a UIPicker at the bottom of screen. What I want to do is I want to open UIPicker from the bottom of screen on click of UIButton as shown in image below

[image: picker position]

I want to know

1. which kind of constraint I have to set initially
2. which kind of constraint I have to implement programmatically and how it will be implemented?

How to get back to its original position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done is, I have set 3 constraint for pickerView as follows.

[image]

Then I set outlet of the bottom space to my view.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint;
```

after then on click of botton I write following logic and my work is done.

```
- (IBAction)showPicker:(id) sender{
    self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    [self.picker setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially pin top of `pickerView` to `bottom` of `SuperView` and then when you want it to show you can pin `bottom` of `pickerView` to bottom of `superView`.

**OR**

You can do higher animation by pinning bottom of pickerView to bottom of superView and set height to 0 and when you want to show set height constant to whatEver height is recquired.

Answer (score 0):

follow the below step.

applied this constraint on your object.

[image]

after that select vertical space constraint and create IBOutlet for it.

[image]

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *TopHeight;

set your desire top margin using below code.it will set new top margin for your object with animation.

```
self.TopHeight.constant = 400;
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```